# The speed of lists in Python

Tags: python, optimization

I have about 10 million pieces of data that need to be spliced ​​into the following form for api sending.  This is my original form, but this splicing is too slow, I wonder if there is a solution with a shorter execution time.

Env: python 3.9.2 mariadb 10.5 debian

Code:

```py
sql = (
            "SELECT team.teamid, team.level, score.id AS scorekey, score.points, score.timestamp, score.`update`, score.lid, score.data, score.userid "
            "FROM score INNER JOIN music ON team.id = score.teamid "
            "WHERE music.type = :type"
        )
        # Add version, songid, and chart to the WHERE clause if specified
        where_clauses = []
        params = {
            "type": type.value,
        }
        if class is not None:
            where_clauses.append("team.class = :class")
            params["class"] = version
        if where_clauses:
            sql += " AND " + " AND ".join(where_clauses)

        # Execute the query
        cursor = self.execute(sql, params)
return [
            (
                UserID(result["userid"]),
                Score(
                    result["scorekey"],
                    result["teamid"],
                    result["level"],
                    result["points"],
                    result["timestamp"],
                    result["update"],
                    result["lid"],
                    result["counts"],
                    self.deserialize(result["data"]),
                ),
            )
            for result in cursor.fetchall()
        ]
```

Time spent: 8.27s

- Data: 110k
- sql.execute: 3.03s
- result return: 5.24s

It's really slow for the real-time calculation part.

I tried to `modify map(list)`, and `loop convenience`, and `remove fetchall()` but those didn't help. Any thoughts on what I should do to speed up the return part?

Comment: `if class is not None` is not valid Python (SyntaxError). The indentation is also broken. Are you sure this is the code your are running?

Comment: Hmm... are you aware that the *return result* time actually includes the time required for fetching the data? What is the time is you simply return the result of `cursor fetchall()` without any further processing?

Comment: How do "10 million pieces of data" and "Data: 110k" relate? That sounds contradictory.

Comment: There are two problems here. First, `sql.execute` is slow and there is likely no way to optimize it expect from changing the database table structure (which certainly not optimal). Unfortunately, we have no information on the database (structure & location) so we cannot really help you. Regarding the `cursor.fetchall()` loop, iterating over 10_000_000 values so to create 100_000_000 objects based on dict-like accesses will never gonna be fast using the CPython interpreter... In fact, this is quite fast already for such an output (<20 nanosecond/fetch), except if 110k is the actual size.

Comment: We also do not have information about what the `deserialize` function does. Please add more information so we can actually help you (something that can be at least barely reproducible).